# In Wasserstein, what is the relationship between $W_2 (\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N},\mathbb{P})$ and $W_2 (\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}^{x},\mathbb{P}^{x})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Before presenting my question (which I already formulate in the title of this post)  is important to establish the context of my problem:

> **Definition:**
>   The $p$-Wasserstein metric $W_{p}(\mu,\nu)$ between $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)$ is defined by
>   $$W_{p}^{p}(\mu,\nu):=\min_{\Pi\in\mathcal{P}(\Xi\times\Xi)}\left\{\int_{\Xi\times\Xi}d^{p}(\xi,\zeta)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta)\: :\: \Pi(\cdot \times\Xi)=\mu(\cdot),\: \Pi(\Xi\times\cdot)=\nu(\cdot)\right\}$$
>   where 
>   $$\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi):=\left\{\mu\in\mathcal{P}(\Xi)\: :\: \int_{\Xi}d^{p}(\xi,\zeta_{0})\mu(d\xi) < \infty\ \mbox{for some }\zeta_{0}\in\Xi\right\}$$
>   where $d$ is a metric on  $\Xi$.

The $p$-Wasserstein metric (with $p\geq 1$) is also defined for any measure in $\mathcal{P}(\Xi)$ the space of all the measures of probability, the only difference is that in that set it can take values as infinite.

We consider $\Xi=\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\xi$ a random vector with support in $\Xi$ and distribution $\mathbb{P}$, let $\widehat{\xi}_{1},\ldots,\widehat{\xi}_{N} $ be a sample of $\xi$, then we consider the empirical distributión given by
$$\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}:=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\delta_{\widehat{\xi}_{i}}.$$
Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ we consider the random variable $\zeta^{x}:=\langle x,\xi\rangle$, let $\mathbb{P}^{x}$ the distribution of $\zeta^{x}$, note that as   $\widehat{\xi}_{1},\ldots,\widehat{\xi}_{N} $ is a sample of $\xi$,  then  $\widehat{\zeta}^{x}_{1},\ldots,\widehat{\zeta}^{x}_{N}$ given  by $\widehat{\zeta}^{x}_{i}:=\langle x,\widehat{\xi}_{i}\rangle$ is a sample of $\zeta^{x}$, therefore,  we have $\widehat{P}^{x}_{N}$ the empirical distribution given by
$$\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}^{x}:=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\delta_{\widehat{\zeta}_{i}^{x}}.$$
From now on we consider the $2$-Wasserstein metric with $d$ as euclidean distance, that is $d(x,y)=\left\|x-y\right\|$ where $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ is the euclidean norm.

**The question:** What is the relationship between $W_2^2(\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N},\mathbb{P})$ and $W^{2}_{2}(\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}^{x},\mathbb{P}^{x})$?

**My attepmt:** I think that $$ W^{2}_{2}(\widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}^{x},\mathbb{P}^{x}) \leq \left\|x\right\|^{2}  W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N} ,\mathbb{P}\right)$$
The next is my attempt to prove it, although there are steps of which I do not feel safe.

We consider $\widehat{\widehat{\xi}}_{1},\ldots,\widehat{\widehat{\xi}}_{M}$ other sample of $\xi$, then we consider $\widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}_{M}$ the empirical distribution determined by this sample. Also, we consider of sample   $\widehat{\widehat{\zeta}}^{x}_{1},\ldots,\widehat{\widehat{\zeta}}^{x}_{M}$ of $\zeta^{x}$ given by $\widehat{\widehat{\zeta}}^{x}_{i}:=\left\langle x, \widehat{\widehat{\xi}}_{i}\right\rangle$ and $\widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}^{x}_{M}$ the empirical distribution determined by this sample.

We know that $ \widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}_{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$ weakly, then,  by Corollary 6.11 in [Villani](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf), we have
$$W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N} ,\widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}_{M}\right)\overset{{\scriptstyle M\rightarrow \infty}}{\longrightarrow}W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N} ,\mathbb{P}\right). \tag{I}$$
Analogously we have $ \widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}^{x}_{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{x}$ weakly, then,  by Corollary 6.11 in [Villani](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf), we have
$$W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}^{x}_{N} ,\widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}^{x}_{M}\right)\overset{{\scriptstyle M\rightarrow \infty}}{\longrightarrow}W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}^{x} ,\mathbb{P}^{x}\right). \tag{II}$$

But note that

$$
\begin{align}
W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}^{x}_{N} ,\widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}^{x}_{M}\right) &= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{M} \lambda_{i,j}\left|\widehat{\zeta}^{x}_{i}-\widehat{\widehat{\zeta}}^{x}_{j}  \right|^{2} \:\left|\: \begin{array}{l} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i,j}=\frac{1}{M},\\ \sum_{j=1}^{M}\lambda_{i,j}=\frac{1}{N},\\ \lambda_{i,j}\geq 0, \\ i=1,\ldots,N,\\ j=1,\ldots,M \end{array}  \right.\right\} \\
&= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{M} \lambda_{i,j}\left|\left\langle x, \widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\rangle-\left\langle x, \widehat{\widehat{\xi}}_{j}\right\rangle   \right|^{2} \:\left|\: \begin{array}{l} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i,j}=\frac{1}{M},\\ \sum_{j=1}^{M}\lambda_{i,j}=\frac{1}{N},\\ \lambda_{i,j}\geq 0, \\ i=1,\ldots,N,\\ j=1,\ldots,M \end{array}  \right.\right\}  \\
&\leq  \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{M} \lambda_{i,j} \left\|x\right\|^{2}\left\| \widehat{\xi}_{i}- \widehat{\widehat{\xi}}_{j}  \right\|^{2} \:\left| \: \begin{array}{l} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i,j}=\frac{1}{M},\\ \sum_{j=1}^{M}\lambda_{i,j}=\frac{1}{N},\\ \lambda_{i,j}\geq 0, \\ i=1,\ldots,N,\\ j=1,\ldots,M \end{array}  \right.\right\} \:\: \begin{array}{l}\mbox{by Hölder}\\ \mbox{inequality}\end{array}\\
&= \left\|x\right\|^{2}W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N} ,\widehat{\widehat{\mathbb{P}}}_{M}\right).
\end{align} 
$$
Therefore, by $(I)$ and $(II)$ we have 
$$W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N}^{x} ,\mathbb{P}^{x}\right)\leq \left\|x\right\|^{2} W_{2}^{2}\left( \widehat{\mathbb{P}}_{N} ,\mathbb{P}\right).$$

**Remark:** I feel that it was a very simple demonstration, for this reason I do not trust my argument, I would like someone to help me see if my reasoning has errors. In my research this result is very important, for that reason I need to know if my idea is correct.

I published my question here because I feel that here are the people trained to answer it.

Comment: Don't have time to check all the details, but your argument looks fine to me.  You show the inequality holds for the appropriate empirical measures, then by weak convergence the same inequality should hold in the limit.